# Mega Shark in Hungry Shark?

Tags: hungry-shark

What is the last shark/beast you can unlock in Hungry Shark for the Kindle Fire? What do you need to do to unlock this menace?

Comment: I've removed the kindle-fire tag.  Unless this game works differently for the various platforms, there's no reason for the tag.

Comment: I appreciate the concern but I would not have added the tag IF the game was the same on all platforms!

Comment: The Kindle Fire uses the Android OS.  Use that tag instead, please.

Comment: @fbueckert take note that Amazon forked Android from the Google version in such a way to lock users to the Amazon Appstore and lock out the Google Play app store. You can get Google Play to work on your Kindle Fire, but it technically voids the warranty.

Comment: @Krazer - Amazon appstore has the latest version of HS:Evolution. Not sure about other HS games

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last shark you can unlock is the megladon. It eats all and can only be killed by starvation.

Comment: In Hungry Shark: Evolution, the last shark is Big Daddy (Dunkleosteus)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify which version of Hungry Shark. So I'll give an answer to the latest version of the game, *Hungry Shark: Evolution* (available on Amazon App Store and thus on Kindle).

The last shark you can unlock in it isn't technically speaking a shark: it's [Dunkleosteus (aka Big Daddy)](http://hungry-shark.wikia.com/wiki/Big_Daddy_%28Dunkleosteus%29).

- In game it can grow up to 30 meters in length, compared to Megalodon's 25, and can dive deeper (see "real life" section below for real shark sizes).
- It can eat anything (all sharks including Big Daddies), as well as things that hurt Megalodon such as large mines, and can more easily break submarines.
- It can still be hurt (and killed) by harpoons/hunder's guns/submarine torpedoes.

Interestingly, in real life, [Dunkleosteus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunkleosteus), while a fish apex predator like Megalodon:

- **wasn't actually a shark at all** (Megalodon - and other sharks - are of class *Chondrichthyes*, and Dunkleosteus was class *Placodermi*, plate-skinned fishes.
- was a lot shorter than the Megalodon. Its full size in real life is about the size of a Great white shark - 10m (33 ft) tops - vs Megalodon's 16m. Totally contrary to the game :)
- They lived in different times: Megalodon 15.9 to 2.6 million years ago, during the Cenozoic Era; and Dunkleosteus in Devonian period (~400M-350M years ago).

There are also "special" extra sharks you can unlock that aren't main-progression sharks (electric, ice, and robot sharks so far)